# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime when passing textbox value created by Ajax Calendar control to variable

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, datetime

I'm trying to pass the date value populated into a textbox by an Ajax calendar extender control to a date variable but I keep getting a 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime' error. I've tried modifying the specific date format when populating the variable but keep getting the same error. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Code:

```
Dim RenewalDate As Date = Date.ParseExact(txtRenewalDate.Text.ToString, "M/dd/yyyy", Nothing)
```

Value showing in textbox: '6/6/2014'

Does it have to do with the format that the calendar extender control uses to populate the textbox?

Comment: Have to tried debugging to see if you are actually getting 6/6/2014 from the web page?

Comment: What Format have you set for calendar extender? I know that CalendarExtender doesn't like some date formats for example: dd-MMM-yyyy. Try setting it to dd-MM-yyyy

Comment: I tried changing the variable type to string and what I get is '#6/6/2014#'.

Comment: Try to call Date.Parse(txtRenewalDate.Text) instead.

Comment: CalendarExtender format is the same as I have specified when trying to populate the variable: "M/dd/yyyy"

Comment: @ PrzemG: I get the same error with Date.Parse(...)

Comment: you have to use "M/d/yyyy" since your date doesnt have 2 digits it will throw an error

Comment: I tried that as well, same error.

Comment: it works here https://dotnetfiddle.net/il1lvC

Comment: OK, I'm actually not getting the date back from the web page now. If I change the variable to string I get a null value back. Why would this be happening? I can see that the CalendarExtender is populating a value into the text box but it's not getting passed back to the variable.

Comment: OK, the issue was that the textbox the calendarextender was populating was set to ReadOnly. I was able see the date value appearing in the textbox after selecting the date but it wasn't passing to the VB code.

Answer (score 0):

StephenT,
Please try below example. I had issue retrieving date from ReadOnly textbox. Our issues may be different, but this may help you.

```
 Dim RenewalDate As String = Request.Form(txtRenewalDate.UniqueID)
```

Comment: Thanks Levi. My problem was resolved when I removed the ReadOnly attribute from the textbox and I was able to use the code I originally posted.